# Import y Export de archivo XLSX, CSV con ajax .net core

Tags: javascript, ajax, .net, .net-core

busco su ayuda ya que necesito subir archivos en formato XLSX y CSV por medio de ajax ya que debo presentar un loader evidenciando el procesamiento del mismo, este mismo archivo es enviado a un controller en donde se realiza su procesamiento y me retorna un file con el CSV o XLSX ya procesado.

Agradezco su ayuda ya que eh buscado diferentes fuentes y no he logrado realizar este proceso.

Answer (score 0):

Para trabajar con documentos office en .net core hay varias librerias, pero te recomiendo que mires estas dos

1. [**NPOI**](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi) >  a .NET library that can read/write Office formats without Microsoft Office installed. No COM+, no interop.
   https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi
2. [**EPPlus**](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus) > Create advanced Excel spreadsheets using .NET
   https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus

Dale una mirada a ambos proyectos, mira el codigo de ejemplo, pruebalos y quedate con el que mas adecuado sea para tu proyecto y tu equipo de desarrollo.

Ejemplo de código

Para **NPOI**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostExporttoExcel()  
{  
string webRootPath = _hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath;  
string fileName = @"Testingdummy.xlsx";  
string URL = string.Format("{0}://{1}/{2}", Request.Scheme, Request.Host, fileName);  
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(webRootPath, fileName));  
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();  
    // --- Below code would create excel file with dummy data----  
using (var fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine(webRootPath, fileName), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))  
{  
    IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();  
    ISheet excelSheet = workbook.CreateSheet("Testingdummy");  

    IRow row = excelSheet.CreateRow(0);  
    row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("ID");  
    row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("Name");  

    row = excelSheet.CreateRow(1);  
    row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(1);  
    row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("Mike");  

    row = excelSheet.CreateRow(2);  
    row.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue(2);  
    row.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("James");  

    workbook.Write(fs);  
}  
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(webRootPath, fileName), FileMode.Open))  
{  
    await fileStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);  
}  
memoryStream.Position = 0;  
return File(memoryStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", fileName);  
    }
```

Para **EPPlus**

```
//Abrir una planilla (o crearla si no existe
var fi=new FileInfo(@"C:\Starwars.xlsx")
using (var p = new ExcelPackage(fi))
    {           
       var ws=p.Workbook.Worksheets["MySheet"];
       Set the cell value using row and column.
       ws.Cells[2, 1].Value = "This is cell A2. It is set to bolds";
       //The style object is used to access most cells formatting and styles.
       ws.Cells[2, 1].Style.Font.Bold=true;
       //Save and close the package.
       p.Save();
    }
```

Enlaces que te pueden ayudar

- [Getting Started with NPOI](https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi/wiki/Getting-Started-with-NPOI)
- [Export And Import Excel Data Using NPOI Library In .NET Core 2 Razor Pages](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/export-and-import-data-using-npoi-library-in-net-core-2-razor-pages/)
- [Here's how to read Excel 2007 document (XLSX) using NPOI libraries](https://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2017/07/npoi-excel-2007.html)
- [EEPlus Getting Started](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/wiki/Getting-Started)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda o guía.

Comment: si lo que pasa es que necesito pasar los datos por un ajax para cargar un loader que le muestre al usuario la carga de los datos, sin embargo ya tengo como logro subir los datos a mi controlador y el ya me esta trabajando los mismos sin embargo no logro escribir un excel desde ajax por que en el controler tengo un retur file pero el no me lo toma.

Comment: return File(resultFinally, "application/vnd.ms-excel", fileNameAlone + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") + "_" + DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss") + extension);


Este es el return file y el no lo esta tomando